# Intercepting touches outside dialog BEFORE dismissal

Tags: android, android-dialogfragment

I have a `DialogFragment` which has an animation on start, and I'm trying to do an animation on close.

I first started by adding a "back" key listener, but my dialog has the `setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true)`. So I would also like to add the transition on touching outside the dialog `fragment` as well.

All methods I tried (AFAIK) are called AFTER the dialog is automatically dismissed on pressing outside. Is there a way to intercept before the dialog goes out of view?

EDIT: this question is still not answered as the proposed solution doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

When dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true); then you just override onCancel() like this:

```
dialog.setOnCancelListener(
new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                //When you touch outside of dialog bounds, 
                //the dialog gets canceled and this method executes.
            }
        }
);
```

Comment: for some reason there is no method onTouchEvent for my DialogFragment to override

Comment: updated my answer, try setting that. Please refer to this link for more detail http://iserveandroid.blogspot.in/2011/04/how-to-dismiss-your-non-modal-dialog.html

Comment: again, onTouchEvent may work for an activity that is themed as a dialog, but not as a dialog fragment. Making the dialog not modal means the activity below it will respond to my clicks, which is something I don't want.

Comment: ok..let me see..Busy with some work, let you know as soon as I got some clue.

Comment: Have you trued overriding onCancel() method of dialog OnCancelListener(), Edited my answer, take a look on that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98801/discussion-between-anshuman-borah-and-rjfares).

Comment: _Set a listener to be invoked when the dialog is canceled.
This will only be invoked when the dialog is canceled. Cancel events alone will not capture all ways that the dialog might be dismissed. If the creator needs to know when a dialog is dismissed in general, use setOnDismissListener(DialogInterface.OnDismissListener)._

*** So it's called after the dialog is cancelled, still not a solution

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method that intercepts both touches outside of the dialog and the Back key. I used it for validation but you can replace the `isValid()` by a function to start the animation and then dismiss the dialog.

```
    fun isValid() = // TODO
    
    // Validate when pressing Back
    dialog.setOnKeyListener { _, keyCode, keyEvent -> // getAction to make sure this doesn't double fire
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && keyEvent.action == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
            !isValid()
        } else false
    }

    // Validate when touching outside to dismiss the dialog
    dialog.window?.let {
        it.callback = object : WindowCallbackWrapper(it.callback) {

            override fun dispatchTouchEvent(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
                if (isOutOfBounds(event)) {
                    if (!isValid()) {
                        return true
                    }
                }
                return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event)
            }

            private fun isOutOfBounds(event: MotionEvent): Boolean {
                return if (event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE) {
                    true
                } else {
                    if (event.action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                        val x = event.x.toInt()
                        val y = event.y.toInt()
                        val slop = ViewConfiguration.get(context).scaledWindowTouchSlop
                        val decorView: View = it.decorView
                        (x < -slop || y < -slop || x > decorView.width + slop || y > decorView.height + slop)
                    } else {
                        false
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```